# Crashing during scrolling because bounds are returning as zero

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

My app is crashing with this message:

> 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'

This is because my zoom scale is calculating to be infinity (divide by zero)

I am trying to experiment with using no Storyboards - so everything is being done programatically. I have two `ViewController's`. The source `ViewController` pushes a new `ViewController` onto the stack like this:

```
..
let destinationVC  = DetailViewController()
destinationVC.setWith(img: photo)
navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
...
```

Now, my `destinationVC` crashes when I zoom out in my `scrollView`. This is because in `updateMinZoomScaleForSize`, the `bounds` are returning as 0. I've tried calling this function in a few other places:

1. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` - still crashes
2. `viewWillLayoutSubviews` - still crashes
3. `viewWillAppear` - still crashes
4. `viewDidAppear` - no crash, but the image "jumps" into place

I've also tried to call `image.setNeedsDisplay()` and `image.setNeedsLayout` in the `setWith(img: UIImage)` method but I still am observing the same results.

Here is the full code for my `destinationVC`

```
private let image : UIImageView = {
    let img = UIImageView()
    img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return img
}()


private lazy var scrollView : UIScrollView! = {
    let scroll = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
    scroll.contentSize = image.bounds.size
    scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return scroll
}()

func setWith(img: UIImage) {
    self.image.image = img
    image.setNeedsDisplay()
    image.setNeedsLayout()
    updateMinZoomScaleForSize(view.bounds.size)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    /// Add scrollview
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(image)
    scrollView.delegate = self
    addScrollViewConstraints()
    addImageConstraints()
}

private func addScrollViewConstraints() {
    let margins = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


}

private func addImageConstraints() {
    image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    image.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    image.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    image.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return image
}

private func updateMinZoomScaleForSize(_ size: CGSize) {
    print(image.bounds.width)
    let widthScale = size.width / image.bounds.width
    let heightScale = size.height / image.bounds.height
    let minScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    scrollView.zoomScale = minScale
}
```

Comment: Also open to any feedback on the approach, so if this is a bad design and this is why I am finding myself in this position please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `.image` property of a `UIImageView` does *not* change the frame of the `UIImageView`.

Try changing your `setWith()` function to this:

```
func setWith(img: UIImage) {
    self.image.image = img
    image.frame.size = img.size
    updateMinZoomScaleForSize(view.bounds.size)
}
```